# Pull admin text value to display on Catalog/ Product/ List

Tags: price, product-attribute, category-attribute

I'm trying to pull the text value from the product page in admin to display under grid mode on catalog/ product/ list.phtml.  Its not pulling the value.

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('scratch_and_dent') == "Yes"): ?>
<p class="scratchDentprice">
<span class=""><?php echo $this->__('Our Price: $'); ?></span>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('scratch_and_dent_price'); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: have enable scratch_and_dent  for product listing from admin> attribute magement

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('scratch_and_dent_price'); ?>
```

It is:

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('scratch_and_dent_price'); ?>
```